# What is the meaning of "Windows [versions]: this value is not available." statement in MSDN?

Tags: windows, winapi

When reading the MSDN documentation for [WinLocalLogonSid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379650%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#WinLocalLogonSid) value of `WELL_KNOWN_SID_TYPE` enumeration, that is:

> **WinLocalLogonSid**
>
> Indicates a SID that matches a local logon group.
>
> > ***Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows 7, Windows Server 2008, Windows Vista, Windows Server 2003, and Windows XP:**  This value is not available.*

there is an *uncertainty of meaning* in the system requirement statement. It can be one of the following meanings:

1. `WinLocalLogonSid` start to exist in Windows 8.
2. In case of the documentation is not yet updated to Windows 8, it can also means that `WinLocalLogonSid` only exists in Windows versions prior to Windows XP.

Unfortunately, those enumeration values were not documented in the header source code.

I made a check for `WinNT.h` from Windows 7 SDK, surprisingly, the `WinLocalLogonSid` was available there. I don't have a definite conclusion for this fact because there is a possibility that *an identifier is declared but not yet implemented*.

So, could someone experienced on this stuffs tell me what is the meaning of such a system requirement statement in MSDN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that it says at the bottom:

> Minimum supported client: Windows XP
>
> Minimum supported server: Windows Server 2003

So yes, it is only Windows 8.